# Select2 createSearchChoice and removing already created choices

Tags: jquery-select2

I am trying to customize select2 and I am overriding createSearchChoice to return an object when the item is not found.

Then `.on('select2-selecting',` I am taking the newly created choice and converting it to a 'real' object (persisting to the server). However, now the 'temporary' choice that was created does not match the object and so select2 is still showing the search term as an option because I created a new and different object and treated the search choice as a temporary entity.

How can I stop select2 from appending any previously created search choices from the results? (I would ideally like to purge select2 from 'knowing' about the previously created search choice)

Comment: I think the issue is the `id` values do not match. What are you setting the `id` to in `createSearchChoice` and on the server? Perhaps you could show your `createSearchChoice` and `.on('select2-selecting'` code. Also, is this a single or multiple select? Backed by a `<select>` or `<input type="hidden">`? Are the choices retrieved via ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select2 will not consider the two items the same unless they have the same `id` values.

Perhaps you could delay the selection of the new item until after it has been persisted to the server. The server would have to return the `id` value that it uses.

createSearchChoice:

```
createSearchChoice: function(term) {
    // We need to make sure the 'select2-selecting' event handler
    // can identify a "temporary" item.
    return { id: '_TEMP_', text: term, isTemp: true };
}
```

on 'select2-selecting':

```
.on('select2-selecting', function(e) {
    var $select = $(this),
        item = e.choice;
    if (item.isTemp) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the item from immediately being selected.
        $.ajax({ // This is the ajax call that persists the new item.
            ...,
            data: { newText: item.text }, // Item text is passed to the server
            success: function(item) { // The server returns the new item.
                // Add the item to the selection.
                // Note: This assumes a multiple select.
                var data = $select.select2('data');
                data.push(item);
                $select.select2('data', data);
            },
            complete: function() {
                $select.select2('close');
            }
        });
    }
})
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mv4gnxfm/1/)

For a single select, the `success` callback would change to:

```
success: function(item) {
    $select.select2('data', item);
},
```

Note: For a single select, the new option will appear in the drop-down even when it is selected because that is the way a single select works.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L67kf8dn/1/)

Comment: Thank you so much, the id is what was getting me.